Google Play App publishing issue with MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
hope you're doing well. I'm facing issues with publishing my app on Google Play and need some advice. I developed an app using Flutter that includes a feature allowing users to save images directly into their gallery for personal backup, as well as saving images in a local folder within the app. Additionally, the app creates a database, but the external storage is solely used for gallery saves. Originally, I implemented the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, which I later realized was overly broad. After my app was rejected initially, I switched to the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, which is more restrictive and only allows the app to save images. For managing the images, I use the Gal package. Despite these adjustments, my app was rejected again. Could anyone help me understand if there's anything additional I should be considering or modifying in my app to comply with Google Play's policies and successfully publish it?
Rejection message: https://dontpad.com/rejectedbygoogle

can u show us your reject message from Google?

Yes! Sorry, i'll add into the question.

ahh.... how bout WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE reject message dude? Above is MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE...

I didn't quite understand what you meant. Could you explain a bit more? I removed all permissions from the AndroidManifest, but my app was still rejected.

you said you were rejected twice. Can i see your second reject message?
